# JPA OneToMany unidirectional mapping with child entity having a composite primary key of which one field is a foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA/Hibernate mapping as follows, in one of my projects where I use **spring-data-jpa** in the persistence layer.

```
@Entity
public class SalesOrder {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Integer id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "salesOrderId", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    List<OrderLine> lines = new ArrayList<>();

    //...
}


@Entity
@IdClass(SalesOrderLinePK.class)
public class SalesOrderLine {
    @Id
    String sku;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "salesOrderId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    Integer salesOrderId;

    //...
}

public class SalesOrderLinePK implements Serializable {
    String sku;
    Integer salesOrderId;
    OrderLinePK() {} 

    OrderLinePK(String sku, Integer salesOrderId) {
        this.sku = sku;
        this.salesOrderId= salesOrderId;
    }
}
```

When I persist a new **Order** entity with some new **OrderLine** children, it gives me an error due to the reason **salesOrderId** field of **SalesOrderLine** is not set, instead, be null.

The following is the particular test case which fails with the error.

```
@Test
void create() {
    SalesOrder item = randomItem(false);
    item = salesOrderService.create(item);

    assertNotNull(item);
    assertNotNull(item.getId());
    assertNotNull(item.getVersion());
}

private SalesOrder randomItem(boolean persistant) {
    String random = RandomString.make(5);
    SalesOrder order = new SalesOrder();
    order.setOrderDate(LocalDate.now());
    order.setOrderState(OrderState.DONE);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        SalesOrderLine item = new SalesOrderLine();
        item.setIdx(i);
        item.setCode(random);
        item.setName("Catalog Item " + random);
        item.setListedPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(120.50));
        item.setDiscount(BigDecimal.valueOf(10));
        item.setSellingPrice(BigDecimal.valueOf(108.50));
        order.getOrderLines().add(item);
    }


    if (persistant) {
        order = salesOrderRepository.save(order);
    }
    return order;
}
```

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I don't want it to make bidirectional either. Could you please help me solve this issue.

Comment: That depends on how your db handles that creation of new `SalesOrderLine` items. I think what you are missing is a `@GeneratedValue` on the `Integer salesOrderId`. But that depends on how your db is configured.

Comment: @AmirSchnell comment is correct. Where do you set the id of SalesOrder?

Comment: Actually I have that annotation in my code. I have forgotten to write it here. Just corrected it in the question code too.

Comment: as i wrote, you need that annotation on `salesOrderId` too.